# Is there a way to instantiate a contract from code_hash without ContractRef

Tags: ink, smart-contract

From the [documentation](https://use.ink/basics/cross-contract-calling), we have 2 ways of instantiating a contract from a code_hash, but both require a `ContractRef`.

In order to obtain `ContractRef` we have to import the contract crate as a dependency into the current project, which might not be ideal in case we only have code_hash of the contract.

So is there a way to instantiate a contract from code_hash without ContractRef?